# How to use ReCaptcha properly?

Tags: javascript, html, recaptcha

I have recaptcha. I've read the documentation. And I need to meet these:

a) handle "onsubmit" of a form

b) execute a recaptcha inside "onsubmit" of a form

c) initially the submit button should be disabled, only after a recaptcha is loaded it should become enable

d) send an ajax request inside "onsubmit" of a form. A page shouldn't be reloaded.

I know how to implement all that one by one. But, it appears to be the case that recaptcha doesn't support all these requirements *at the same time*.

Namely:

1)

```
// my_script.js
window.onRecaptchaLoaded = function() {
  grecaptcha.render("my_recaptcha123", {
    "sitekey": "fdsfdsfd",
    "callback": recaptchaOnSubmit
  });
}
```

Now, how can I handle `onsubmit` of a form and `recaptchaOnSubmit` of recaptcha? What's a relationship between them? If I have a single "onSubmit" it won't work as I want to - I've tried.

2)   I have this:

```
https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onRecaptchaLoaded&render=explicit
```

But now this doesn't allow me to call "grecaptcha.execute()" inside "onsubmit" of a form?

```
Uncaught Error: grecaptcha.execute only works with invisible captcha.
```

**Previously**, without "?onload=onRecaptchaLoaded&render=explicit", I could call "grecaptcha.execute()" inside "onsubmit" of a form -- this is what I need.

But! **Previously** also **without** `?onload=onRecaptchaLoaded&render=explicit` it didn't allow me to have `window.onRecaptchaLoaded = function() {` And I need it to meet the c)

How can I deal with all that?

Comment: Is your form button named "submit"? see [this article](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/recaptcha/ic8cuIxex2E)

Comment: @RamblinRose, yes, but that's only a part of an answer

Comment: @RamblinRose, also **how can I handle onsubmit of a form and recaptchaOnSubmit of recaptcha? What's a relationship between them? If I have a single "onSubmit" it won't work as I want to - I've tried.**